# How do I install OpenSP 1.5.2, the SGML (and XML) parser for w3c local validator on windows?

Tags: perl, w3c, validation, activestate

How do I install OpenSP 1.5.2, the SGML (and XML) parser for w3c local validator on windows?

Answer (score 0):

The instruction for [installing the W3C validator on Windows](http://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html). You probably need to upgrade to the latest version of SGML::Parser::OpenSP > 0.991